# The definition of the Church numerals in combinatory logic

Tags: logic, formal-languages, combinatory-logic

Hindley & Seldin define ([1] Definition 4.2, p. 48) the Church numerals as follows: (I'm paraphrasing to save space. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8DEa.jpg)'s the original page.)

> For every $n \in \{0,1,\dots\}$, the Church numeral for $n$ is
>   $$
> \overline{n} := (SB)^n(KI)
> $$
>   where we used the abbreviations
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> X^nY &:= \underset{n}{\underbrace{X(X(\dots(X}}Y))) \\
> B &:= S(KS)K
> \end{align}
> $$

They proceed to claim (ibid. Note 4.4, p. 48) that $\overline{n} = [x,y].x^ny$ for all $n\neq 1$.

I don't see why this claim holds. For instance, when $n=2$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
[x,y].x^ny &= [x].\Big([y].\big(x(xy)\big)\Big) \\
&= [x].\Big(S\big([y].x\big)\big([y].(xy)\big)\Big) \\
&= [x].\big(S(Kx)x\big) \\
&= S\Big([x].\big(S(Kx)\big)\Big)([x].x) \\
&= S\Big(S([x].S)\big([x].(Kx)\big)\Big)I \\
&= S\big(S(KS)K\big)I \\
&= SBI \\
&= (SB)^1I \\
&\neq (SB)^2(KI) \\
&= \overline{n}
\end{align}
$$

I checked the textbook's official [errata list](http://www.users.waitrose.com/~hindley/ICL2Errata.pdf), but this is not listed there.

What am missing?

---

[1] J. Roger Hindley & Jonathan P. Seldin. (2008) *Lambda-Calculus and Combinators - An Introduction*. Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 1):

The following step isn't correct:

$$(SB)^1I \ne (SB)^2(KI)$$

because $(SB)Iab = a(ab)$ and $SB(SB(KI))ab = a(ab)$ using $Bxyz = x(yz)$.

An alternative (more straightforward) check that doesn't require the deduction thm transform you are using:

$$\begin{align}
%
\bar{2}fx &= (SB)^2(KI)fx \\
%
&= SB(SB(KI))fx \\
%
&= Bf(SB(KI)f)x \\
%
&= f(SB(KI)fx) \\
%
&= f(Bf(KIf)x) \\
%
&= f(f(KIfx)) \\
%
&= f(f(Ix)) \\
%
&= f(fx) \\
%
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. However, I think your derivation is wrong, because you leave out the parentheses surrounding the sub term $KI$. Up until the fourth step it doesn't make a difference, however step no. five, namely $f(SBKIfx)=f(BI(KI)fx)$ is incorrect. If you put in the parentheses as appropriate you'll see that actually $\overline{2}fx\rhd f^2x$.

Comment: You are right, I'll update this.

Comment: I gave you an upvote, because you made me realize that $(SB)^1Iab\equiv_w(SB)^2(KI)ab$ for all CL-terms $a,b$. However, I'm not check-marking your answer, because it does not quite answer my question, since my question refers to syntactic identity, in other words, the textbook claims that for every $n\neq1$ the expression $\overline{n}$ is exactly the same expression as $(SB)^n(KI)$, and clearly $(SB)^1I$ is not the same expression as $(SB)^2(KI)$.

Comment: How could each $\lambda xy.x^ny$ possibly be textually equal to $(SB)^n(KI)$ ?  One has a $\lambda$ and one doesn't.  Is your book trying to define "syntactic" (I hate when people use that word) equivalence in terms of the $\lambda$ to $SKI$ transform?

Comment: The question is framed in the language of combinatory logic, not of lambda calculus. The symbol $\lambda$ is not part of the language.